# Button showing when adding new fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment on top of another (Fragment A -> Fragment B), yet when I do, the button from the first fragment is showing through. I don't get why adding a fragment on top of another is showing content from the first.

Here is the first Activity. It holds the first fragment (Fragment A):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Fragment A, that calls the second fragment (Fragment B):

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

        public MainActivityFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Button startButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
            startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    GameSetupFragment newGame = new GameSetupFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .addToBackStack("MainActivity")
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, newGame)
                            .commit();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Here is the class for Fragment B:

```
public class GameSetupFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_board_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here are the xml files for each:

Activity_Main.xml (Main Activity):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.blaine.tictactoe.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is xml for fragment B (fragment_main.xml)

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="367dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="367dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="74dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="74dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Content_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.blaine.tictactoe.fragments.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

Fragment B code (game_board_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is just a test"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what the app looks like when it runs:

[image: First screen]

[image: Second screen]

Comment: try it with removing tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" from the Content_main layout. You have to add this fragment from your mainactivity onCreate method using frgament tansaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Content_main.xml** take FrameLayout and try to open your fragment in it. e.g.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and in your **onCreate** of **MainActivity**, use below code to open your first fragment like this:

```
String fragmentName = targetFragment.getClass().getName();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment targetFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
manager.popBackStack();
manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, fragmentName)
                .addToBackStack(fragmentName)
                .commit();
```

Comment: I just figured this out. But this is the right answer. Thanks for the answer.